# How to calculate internal partition function for atom

Tags: plasma-physics

I am writing my own argon plasma simulation code. For the moment I want to get equilibrium composition of argon plasma. I know that to get plasma number density I need to calculate the internal partition function. Previously I had no idea to calculate it so I just used data from the publication PARTITION FUNCTIONS AND THERMALDYNAMIC PROPERTIES OF ARGON PLASMA by Drellishak et al. and do some silly fitting work. But now I have to calculate the derivative of it as well. So I think it's better for me to use the correct way to get it.

I looked up the data from NIST, for example neutral Argon:

[image]

And I just use the relation (2J+1)*exp(-ei/kT) to calculate for each level and get the sum of all levels. The results for lower temperatures of argon1 to argon4 are in good agreement with Drellishak's result, but the discrepancy   becomes larger and larger when temperatures rise above 10000K, and my results are much lower.

Could someone tell me the right way to calculate internal partition function with the help of NIST data? I am really highly unfamiliar with this field.

Thanks in advance,

Peng

Comment: Could you link the NIST page (and perhaps also make the data table more clean)?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I am quite new in this forum. The nist link is follows:

https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html

The input Ar0 in the blank of represents neutral argon , Ar1 for singly charged argon

Thanks.

Comment: Great, now it is much better.